# In Delphi is there a way to bring back Snap to screen when drag and dock is enabled

Tags: delphi, dock

When `DragKind := dkDock` on a form it no longer automatically snaps maximized when dragged to the top of the screen, or tiled left/right when dragged to the left or right of the screen respectively.

Is there a way of re-enabling this easily?

To reproduce on Win 7 or later.  Create a blank VCL app, run it.  Click the titlebar and drag it to the top of the screen - it should automatically maximize.  Now set the DragKind to dkDock and try it again it will no longer automatically maximize.

Comment: What is "snapping maximized", if you don't mind? Should it fill the entire work area like a maximized window?

Comment: When I set DragKind dkDock in D2007 and XE2, what I see is a horribly flickering, terribly lagging drag rectangle. Even vanishes altogether sometimes.

Comment: @Sertac, it's a [feature introduced in Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snap). While dragging a window, move the mouse to the very top of the screen, and then let go. The window will be maximized, unless you've disabled the feature in Control Panel.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I've made the question slightly clearer, and yes the laggyness is also a problem.  The maximization feature that Rob Kennedy mentions disappears when DragKind is set to dkDock, and I would like it to continue to work.

Comment: @RobKennedy Yes, this is the feature of which I speak.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, and Alister. I understand the question/problem now.

Comment: Ugh, why would you want this?  This is a horrible "feature" that gets in my way far more than it helps. If I put something *near* the edge of a window, that doesn't mean I want other edges of the window I'm working on to move when I didn't do anything to them!

Comment: @MasonWheeler personally I use this feature all the time when dragging between monitors, however like it or not it's more about keeping the default behaviour.

Comment: I think the answer would be no as WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN is never delivered to the default window procedure. Most of the lag seems to be because of the code in TControl.DefaultDockImage.

Comment: Indeed, I use this "feature" extensively, also with multiple monitors. If you have only one monitor, I can see how it can be annoying. But both my workstations, at home and at work, have multiple monitors.

Comment: I think it is perfectly logical - in the OS point of view - that if your form is set to be "docking" it also docks onto the edge of the screen instead of mindlessly changing size and shape. So what you want is your form differentiating based on what it is docked to. I don't think the OS is capable/prepared to that, so IMHO it is a behavior you should implement if you want it.